# Changing the content of layout such as text and images before starting the Intent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-event

I have 2 views, `MainActivity` and `UnitActivity`. In main activity there are some buttons and when user clicks on them I want to bring uo `UnitActivity`.

In `UnitActivity` layout file there are some views like TextView. For example, if the user clicks on a button called `btn_marine` I want to fill the layout with information about marine (a unit in starcraft game, if you know :P).

So my idea is to when user click on button of each unit I fill the text and images of the `UnitActivity` layout with the information I have about that unit.

At the moment I am trying to hard code this I mean before starting the intent, and I have events for buttons in `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`:

```
Button btn_marine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_unit_marine);
btn_marine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnitActivity.class);
        TextView unitNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUnitName);
        unitNameView.setText("Marine!"); //this is line 28 with error
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

But as soon as I click the button application exits with this error in `logcat`:

```
07-29 14:56:03.906  12696-12696/com.eetutorials.terranmate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.eetutorials.terranmate.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So my question is what is the problem in my code, and also, what you think is the best way to do such thing? I tried to create a `Unit` class that holds information about each unit but I dont know how can I fill the Intent from that class.

I mean how can I pass that class to `UnitActivity` so the views automatically gets populated?

This is for example `Unit` class I wanted to make:

```
public class Unit
{
    private String Name;
    private String HitPoint;
    private String Armor;
    private DamageModifiers DamageModifier;
    private String BaseDamage;
    private String Description;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getHitPoint() {
        return HitPoint;
    }

    public void setHitPoint(String hitPoint) {
        HitPoint = hitPoint;
    }

    public String getArmor() {
        return Armor;
    }

    public void setArmor(String armor) {
        Armor = armor;
    }

    public DamageModifiers getDamageModifier() {
        return DamageModifier;
    }

    public void setDamageModifier(DamageModifiers damageModifier) {
        DamageModifier = damageModifier;
    }

    public String getBaseDamage() {
        return BaseDamage;
    }

    public void setBaseDamage(String baseDamage) {
        BaseDamage = baseDamage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: `R.id.textViewUnitName` is declared in UnitActivity layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the thing is, you can't edit a view if you haven't set your layout. Thats where you're nullpointer is coming from; your current Layout doesn't have the textView you're looking for.

What you can do, is pass through your info through an intent to the new activity and switch it there

```
Button btn_marine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_unit_marine);
btn_marine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnitActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("unitType","marine")
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And in your next activity's onCreate, after you set the layout:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String unitType = extras.getString("unitType");
 if (unitType.equals("marine")) {
 TextView unitNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUnitName);
    unitNameView.setText("Marine!");
 }
```

etc etc.

Its rough, because passing it as a string is a bad idea (pass it as a switchable object, theres tons of units man!), and put the view switching in its own function / class so you don't clutter up your onCreate(). But the general logic of passing things through in Android is here, you can figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way. You are trying to access `Views` in a different `layout`. You can't update the `Views` until you have inflated the `layout` such as calling `setContentView()` in your next `Activity`.

What you can do is make the variables in `Unit.java` as `static` variables then set them when the button is clicked so something like in `MainActivity`

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnitActivity.class);
    Unit.Name = "Marine!";
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

then in `UnitActivity`

```
public void onCreate(...)
{
     super....
     setContentView(...);
     TextView unitNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUnitName);
     String name = Unit.Name;
      unitNameView.setText(name);
```

So your `Unit.java` would look more like

```
    public class Unit
{
    public static String Name;
    public static String HitPoint;
    public static String Armor;
    public DamageModifiers DamageModifier;
    public static String BaseDamage;
    public static String Description;
```

And get rid of most of your `getters/setters` and access the variable values statically and it will be faster. Also note that `static` variables can be destroyed by the OS if it needs memory but going from one `Activity` to the next and getting the data will be fine.

Comment: I think to make a more modular and readable class he'd be best off not persisting it as a static variable. He could pass the entire unit object through the Intent and use it on the other side. No need to add a helper function just to pass something through one activity transaction!

Comment: @Vee if its just that one variable to pass then I agree. There were many variables in that class so I don't know how many the OP needs to pass. If its a lot then I don't like using `putExtra` for many variables.

Comment: for sure, but if he does it right, like I said he can just pass through the entire Unit object and deal with it all on the other side! 

If he's using tons of variables, static is the way to go. But at that point you'd think he'd be using a DB

Comment: Well I do have tons of variables to deal with...I was thinking if I can have an XML file for each unit and then parse them and send them to the activity...too bad my Java knowledge is non existing...wish it was .NET !!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NullPointerException` because your button is in UnitActivity layout. I think the best way to achieve what you want to do (pass a class to the other activity) is to use the [android parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

You implement parcelable in you class like this ([How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable)) :

```
public class Unit implements Parcelable{
    private String atrribute1;
    ...
    ...
    // Constructor
    public Unit(String attribute1,...){
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
   }
   // Getter and setter methods
   .........
   .........

   // Parcelling part
   public Unit(Parcel in){
       String[] data = new String[3];

       in.readStringArray(data);
       this.attribute1 = data[0];
       ... = data[1];

   }

   @Оverride
   public int describeContents(){
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.attribute1,...});
   }
   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
       public Unit createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new Unit(in); 
       }

       public Unit[] newArray(int size) {
           return new Unit[size];
       }
   };
```

}

You will be able to do something like this in your MainActivity:

```
intent.putExtra("Unit", new Unit("something",...));
```

and retrieve it like that in your UnitActivity

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
Unit unit = (Unit) data.getParcelable("Unit");
```

Comment: hmm I think there is no overload for `putExtra` to put a `Unit` object in it!

Comment: That's why you need to create a parcelable, did you look it up?